# Is it possible to listen from the UI to the change of a variable from an async function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an asynchronous function where it calls other asynchronous functions where they all return void, just like the main one, I do this to call my APIs. However, what I would like is that when a function finishes, it saves a String to a variable, and every time it changes, show it in the UI.

```dart
 Future<Either<void, Failure>> getFunctions() async {
    try {
      await functionOne();

      changeValue;

      await functionTwo();

      changeValue;
    
      await functionThree();

      changeValue;

    } catch (e, s) {

    }
  }

 Text(
   putHereTheVariable,
 ),
```

Comment: you need a `Stream` for multiple async values, not `Future`, more here: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams

Comment: have you used `acync*` generator?

Comment: I changed Future for Stream with async* and yield every `changeValue` and it works !

Comment: yes, async* generator and yield is the most easy way, you could also use `StreamController` but it is more "technical" way

Comment: I am interested in the "technical" way, do you have documentation on this? Thx !

Comment: for example https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-stream-basics-for-beginners-eda23e44e32f

Answer (score 0):

You should update the state when you call `changeValue`. Then `putHereTheVariable` also changes.

Comment: I change the Future function for a Stream function, and with that, It works ! thx for your answer